# Can we create SharePoint 2010 workflow using visual studio 2015 for sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, visual-studio-2015

When I created visual studio workflow for SharePoint hosted apps, it will create 2013 workflow, can I create SharePoint 2010 workflow using visual studio 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SP online you can only use Sharepoint Designer to create declarative workflows. No custom logic. What you can do is to make a web request to external service that will do whatever custom logic you need to and apply to Sharepoint as web request.

Comment: we can use VS workflow inside sharepoint hosted app for sharepoint online but custom code can't applicable. Exactly what i am doing, I created sharepoint hosted app and within this i created state machine workflow, that workflow working fine, but its show 2013 workflow, Is there any way to make it 2010 template, any option available there in VS to do this.